# Pay without need to login WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For a WooCommerce webshop we send out a lot of payment links through email. Before getting to the payment page customers are obligated to login first. We would like the customer to be able to complete payment without logging in as often they don't know their password because of different company departments.

I found this code but this only lets the administrator pay without logging in:

```
function your_custom_function_name($allcaps, $caps, $args)
{
    if (isset($caps[0])) {
        switch ($caps[0]) {
        case 'pay_for_order':
            $user_id = $args[1];
            $order_id = isset($args[2]) ? $args[2] : null;

            // When no order ID, we assume it's a new order
            // and thus, customer can pay for it

            if (!$order_id) {
                $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = true;
                break;
            }

            $user = get_userdata($user_id);
            if (in_array('administrator', (array)$user->roles)) {
                $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = true;
            }

            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            if ($order && ($user_id == $order->get_user_id() || !$order - > get_user_id())) {
                $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = true;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return $allcaps;
}

add_filter('user_has_cap', 'your_custom_function_name', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks but already enabled guest checkout. Problem is it's not guest checkout but orders are assigned to customers so I need to get a work around for them not to get the login form but checkout immediately.

Comment: if that code working correctly as you want for administrator you simply need to change this line 

  if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) )  

to your customer role instead

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wouldnt I need to change administrator in Some sort of Guest role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is working function with all users just test it :

```
function your_custom_function_name( $allcaps, $caps, $args ) {
if ( isset( $caps[0] ) ) {
switch ( $caps[0] ) {
case 'pay_for_order' :


$order_id = isset( $args[2] ) ? $args[2] : null;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$user = $order->get_user();
$user_id = $user->ID;

// When no order ID, we assume it's a new order
// and thus, customer can pay for it
if ( ! $order_id ) {
  $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = true;
  break;
}

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

if ( $order && ( $user_id == $order->get_user_id() || ! $order->get_user_id() ) ) {
  $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = true;
}
break;
}
}

return $allcaps;
}

add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'your_custom_function_name', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a different solution for this problem, allowing anyone who has the WooCommerce-generated Payment URL (which includes the Order Key) to complete the payment for that order. (So we retain some of the security/protection, rather than just allowing anyone to pay for anything and see any order.)

```
function allow_payment_without_login( $allcaps, $caps, $args ) {
    // Check we are looking at the WooCommerce Pay For Order Page
    if ( !isset( $caps[0] ) || $caps[0] != 'pay_for_order' )
        return $allcaps;
    // Check that a Key is provided
    if ( !isset( $_GET['key'] ) )
        return $allcaps;

    // Find the Related Order
    $order = wc_get_order( $args[2] );
    if( !$order )
        return $allcaps; # Invalid Order

    // Get the Order Key from the WooCommerce Order
    $order_key = $order->get_order_key();
    // Get the Order Key from the URL Query String
    $order_key_check = $_GET['key'];

    // Set the Permission to TRUE if the Order Keys Match
    $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = ( $order_key == $order_key_check );

    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'allow_payment_without_login', 10, 3 );
```

Using this function, a user visiting a URL which has an Order Number, and the associated Order Key, will be able to complete the payment, but if the Order Key is not valid, or not present, then it will fail.

Examples:

- *your.domain/checkout/order-pay/987/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_5c4155dd4462c*
  **PASS** if "wc_order_5c4155dd4462c" is Order Key for Order #987
- *your.domain/checkout/order-pay/987/?pay_for_order=true*
  **FAIL** as No Key Parameter Present
- *your.domain/checkout/order-pay/987/*
  **FAIL** as No Key Parameter Present

Answer (score 0):

**Here's my solution that also works with WooCommerce Subscriptions.** Subscription renewals also require the user to be logged in. My function gets the user from the order id passed in the payment link, then checks if the id and order key match and limits the login to subscribers and customers for security reasons. The user is logged in via wp_set_auth_cookie() before WooCommerce checks the login status.

Paste this code in your plugin or your theme's functions.php file.

```
/**
 * Pay for Order or Subscription if Logged Out - WooCommerce Checkout
 */
function glunz_log_in_user_from_payment_link(){
    global $wp;
    if ( isset( $_GET['pay_for_order'] ) && isset( $_GET['key'] ) && isset( $wp->query_vars['order-pay'] ) && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $order_key = $_GET['key'];
        $order_id  = isset( $wp->query_vars['order-pay'] ) ? $wp->query_vars['order-pay'] : absint( $_GET['order_id'] );
        $order     = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $user_id   = $order->get_user_id();
        $user      = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

        // Check if order key corresponds with order and the status of the payment is pending or failed
        if ( wcs_get_objects_property( $order, 'order_key' ) === $order_key && $order->has_status( array( 'pending', 'failed' ) ) ) {
            // For security reasons we want to limit this function to customers and subscribers
            if ( in_array( 'customer', $user->roles ) || in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles ) ) {
                // Log the user in
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
                wp_set_current_user($user_id);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
add_action( 'send_headers', 'glunz_log_in_user_from_payment_link', 0 );
```